# Using @google-cloud function from Angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, google-cloud-platform

I want to invoke @google-cloud/translate from a service in an Angular project.

The Node.js example provided here works for me:
https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/quickstart-client-libraries-v3

When trying to replicate this inside an Angular service, I get the following compile errors when starting up the local web server using "ng serve" (actually "ionic serve", since this is an Ionic/Angular project but I doubt that matters).

```
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/google-gax/build/src/operationsClient.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './operations_client_config' in '****\audio\node_modules\google-gax\build\src'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '****\audio\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/aws-sign2/index.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '****\audio\node_modules\aws-sign2'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/aws4/aws4.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '****\audio\node_modules\aws4'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/ecc-jsbn/index.js
(and many more)
```

The **** is just the rest of my project path.

The sample node.js code which works locally is in  https://pastebin.com/mniWXfj9. Getting that running was simple:

```
npm install --save @google-cloud/translate
npm install --save gcp-metadata
npm update
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="<path to creds>"
node sample.js
```

How can I get that same code to work in my Angular project? Thank you.

Comment: It looks like `crypto` module was missing on Angular part. Why don't you try to install it via npm?

Comment: Thanks, I tried `npm install crypto --save` but the crypto error and all others are still there.

Comment: @royappa did you find a fix? I run into the same issue with the ./operations_client_config

Comment: Sorry @mikegross, no. I resolved indirectly by moving the translation code into a Firebase cloud function. It works fine there. It was anyway something I should have been calling at the server side and not from code running in a client browser.

Comment: @royappa makes sense, I will take the same approach